# Closest to NetBeans for Classic ASP

Tags: netbeans, asp-classic

Are there any code editors like Netbeans for Classic ASP?

I find these especially helpful:

1. A summary of functions per page without reading through lines of code.
2. `See Usage` and `Navigate > Goto Declaration` (SO HELPFUL!)
3. Syntax highlighting and showing problems immediately.

I saw something that said allow `<% %>` in your code for classic ASP, but i don't think that is for straight classic asp development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the IDE for classic ASP and VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702/what-is-the-ide-for-classic-asp-and-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

I've coded classic ASP a long time, and my preferred editor is easily Notepad++. 
Though it doesn't have all the features you want, I'm confident that a plugin or two could solve some of it.

Visual studio sucks is so many ways that I would rather use Notepad or DOS :)

Comment: Well each to his own.  How do debug ASP code? Please explain in what ways you find the Visual Studio sucks when developing an ASP website and how is Notepad++ superior?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: It's my personal opinion and I understand that many others won't agree to my answer. I doo however feel that VS tries to hard: It adds stuff without my conscent, it changes file encodings, does'nt respect tab indents and so on. But as you say, if you need to debug I guess VS is your only choice.

Comment: There are times when VS addes unwanted ID elements.  I can't ever found that VS "changes file encodings" of its own accord and I find its Tab handling makes reasonable choices (most of which it highly configurable to your taste).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying some editors for classic asp old websites and always return to dreamweaver (my latest update was to cs5). Not sure it has all the things you want but is the one that helps me the most on classic asp.

Anyway, just I've found this thread when looking for a way to code asp with netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

We have used **[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**, or Visual Studio Code for legacy ASP classic code. *It is **not** Visual Studio!*

It has a plenty of extensions, including some for ASP classic syntax highlight. It has been very useful. But do not expect too much of any IDE when using ASP classic.